# resize an element depending on avalible space while maintaining ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website which embeds my twitch.tv stream and chat.

I want the chat to be fixed to the side of the page at a specific width and using all of its vertical space. And the actual stream to use the rest of the horizontal space while maintaining the same width/height ratio so there arent any black borders.

after following basic tutorials, this is what I came up with so far:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Twitch Stream</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #chat {
        float:left;
        width:350px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }
    #stream {
        position:fixed;
        float:right;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#00FF00;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <iframe id="chat" src="http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="500" width="350"></iframe>
 <iframe id="stream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im probably going about this the wrong way, any help would be advised

Comment: I updated my answer. you may take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at code snippet result and tell me if this is what you are looking for. if not please explain more.

```css
#chat{
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
#stream{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 350px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Twitch Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <iframe id="chat" src="http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <iframe id="stream" src="http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he wants chat to be specific width

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly except the stream goes off-screen, I would like the stream to automatically resize so that it fits all monitors while still maintaining ratio, thanks.

Comment: Remove height:100% from stream and let it fit as much as it needs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question well here is your answer. You put your #chat to left, and make #stream to take rest of page space.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #chat {
        position:absloute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:350px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }
    #stream {
        position:relative;
        margin-right:350px;
        width: auto;
        background-color:#00FF00;
    }
</style>
```